# How to calculate how fast the data transfer in hadoop is using distcp

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I'm using distcp to move files between two hadoop clusters. How can I check the rate at which the data is moving between any two clusters?

Comment: I know you are not looking for that (that's why I add this as a comment), but a dummy solution would be to run the distcp command using the `time` command, and then divide the data size by the returned time. (https://linux.die.net/man/1/time)

Comment: check this link might yo will get some clarity https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2016/02/05/fast-can-data-transferred-hadoop-clusters-using-distcp/